# How to do an update sql query using a sub select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update two columns in this table. I have the select query working but the update part of is does not.

Here is what I have so far.

```
    UPDATE A
SET foo = 'bar'
car = 'bmw'
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
    ON A.col1 = B.colx
    AND A.STATUS = B.STATUS
WHERE A.nbr = '1234'
      and A.STATUS IN (K,Y)
      and A.FILE_TYPE = 'R'
```

Comment: The documentation for [Mysql update statement](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-data.aspx)

Comment: Put a comma between the two columns being updated, i.e. `SET foo = 'bar', car = 'bmw'`. Also, what does "does not work" mean? Does it give an error or does the SQL execute and not give you the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a `WHERE` clause (and the keyword `SET` only once):

```
UPDATE random_table
SET column_1 = 'x', 
    column_2 = 'y'
WHERE status = 'y';
```

Comment: Can you please look at the updated query above and let me know what I am doing wrong –

Comment: @TimScott this query has nothing to do with with your original question. If your requirement is different you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    update random_table
    set column_1 = 'x', column_2 = 'y'
    from random_Table
    where status = 'y'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please look at the updated query above and let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Could you please post your full query?

Comment: the query above is the full query.

Comment: You need ' ' at set values. And use the keyword SET once. In your situtation: Your query needs to like SET foo='bar' , car='bmw'

Comment: I did that and the error is giving me is that its not properly ended.

Comment: I cant help you due to i need to see your tables and your sample result. If you have to chance post your table and your sample result i might can help you.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.